# Convert String Builder to Integer in c#

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

I am new programmer in C# and I wanna know if there is a direct way to convert from StringBuilder to int. I have the following code. On the last line of the code I get an error.

```
StringBuilder newnum = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = x.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    newnum.Append(x[i]);  
}
int x = Convert.ToInt32(newnum);
```

Comment: Why use `StringBuilder` for this? You can have more than a handful of digits in your final number so the coding overhead is not worth using `StringBuilder`. Just use normal string concatenation or LINQ.

Comment: In fact, this would work - `int x = Convert.ToInt32(String.Join("", x.Reverse()));`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can solve this problem by simply converting the `StringBuilder` to `String` before passing it to the `Convert.ToInt32` method;

You have three different options for converting textual data to an Integer:

```
1:
int i = int.Parse(sb.ToString());

2:
int i = Convert.ToInt32(sb.ToString());

3:
int i;
int.TryParse(sb.ToString(), out i);
```

Comment: No idea. I'm also a bit surprised to see _two_ downvotes for my humble post :).

Comment: @AlexD: I think we got the downvote because we demonstrated the solution, but we didn't point out to the problem. I've just edited my answer and added the cause of the error too.

Answer (score 2):

```
int x = Convert.ToInt32(newnum.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int x = int.parse(newnum.tostring());
```